# How to refresh UI of android App While Using StartActivityForResult..?

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello everyone I'm using working on android app in this app I need to complete a task.
The task is I need to filter data according to result.
I am starting the new activity **DateFilters** 
like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,DateFilters.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

After finish the task of date filter activity come back in **MainActivity**.

Here is the code of activity on result:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  ArrayList tempdata1 = new ArrayList();
  if (requestCode == 1) {
    Menu menu = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
      String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
      Log.i("Date Filter Result",result);
      tempdata1 =  mydatahelper.getStringToArrayList(result);
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
      //Write your code if there's no result
    }
  }
}//onActivityResult
```

I want  to change settings menu with this condition.

```
if (tempdata1.size() > 0) {
    //if this condition is true then update the ui 
}
```

Comment: what is settings menu?

Comment: setting menu is a icon of  calander first its look unchecked.
and if filter is applyed then it needs to changed to checked.
here is the demo image

Comment: I'm not getting you point... if setting menu is check box then just add menu. setChecked(true) if your condition is true.

Comment: i Want Changing options menu icon in actionbar  according to condition

if   tempdata1.size()>0  mean   filter is applyed .

Now if filter is Applyed then change the actionvar manu icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private MenuItem item;    
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_download, menu);
    item = menu.findItem(R.id.exam_download);
    return true;
}

if(tempdata1.size()>0){
//if this condition is true then update the ui
    item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_filter);
}
```